# JDK7 translucency + jframe + jcombobox

Tags: java, swing, jcombobox, java-7, translucency

there seems to be a problem when I have a jComboBox in a jFrame that is using translucency. When I click on the dropdown, a white background appears to cover other components but the items in the dropdown are not shown. Each item only appear once my mouse hover over it. The borders doesnt seems to be around as well.

Any workaround for this?

Thanks!

Comment: Maybe you will provide some piece of code so that one could help you?

Answer (score 2):

I am also facing the same problem.

Quick fix:

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.event.*;
class WindowOpaqueTest2{
  public JComponent makeUI() {
    JPanel p = new JPanel();
    p.setBackground(new Color(.5f,.5f,.5f,.5f));
    p.add(new JComboBox<String>(new String[] {"aaa", "bb", "c"}));
    JComboBox c = new JComboBox<String>(new String[] {"aaa", "bb", "c"});
    c.addPopupMenuListener(new PopupMenuListener() {
      @Override public void popupMenuWillBecomeVisible(final PopupMenuEvent e) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
          @Override public void run() {
            JComboBox c = (JComboBox)e.getSource();
            Object o = c.getAccessibleContext().getAccessibleChild(0);
            if(o instanceof JComponent) { //BasicComboPopup
              ((JComponent)o).repaint();
            }
          }
        });
      }
      @Override public void popupMenuWillBecomeInvisible(PopupMenuEvent e) {}
      @Override public void popupMenuCanceled(PopupMenuEvent e) {}
    });
    p.add(c);
    return p;
  }
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
      @Override public void run() { createAndShowGUI(); }
    });
  }
  public static void createAndShowGUI() {
    JFrame.setDefaultLookAndFeelDecorated(true);
    JFrame f = new JFrame();
    //com.sun.awt.AWTUtilities.setWindowOpaque(f, false);
    f.setBackground(new Color(0,true)); //1.7.0
    f.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    f.getContentPane().add(new WindowOpaqueTest2().makeUI());
    f.setSize(320, 240);
    f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    f.setVisible(true);
  }
}
```